# I need to know how to fix this plaster corner

Tags: plaster

This is in my dining room. The crack extends to the ceiling. 
Can someone advise me on how to repair it?

[image]

Comment: My concern would be more for the cause than actually what we can see - have you got any extra information about the house? (damp, work recently done, on the house, when the crack started to appear?)

Comment: looks to me like there's been movement on the X and Y axis, i wouldn't trust a repair, it's FUBAR...

Comment: I really have to agree with the above comments.  Tear this out, find the root cause, fix that, then re-finish it properly.  No quick and easy fix on this one I'm afraid.